# ASP.NET MVC Two file upload, different destinations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to upload two different files into two different database fields on same form.

```
------------------------------------
reportid | name | image | template |
------------------------------------
```

this is the table look. So I want to upload files to image and template. My model:

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public byte[] Template { get; set; }

}
```

My Create method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Report report, HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpPostedFileBase temp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    report.Image = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }

            if (temp != null && temp.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    temp.InputStream.CopyTo(ms1);
                    report.Template = ms1.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
            db.Reports.Add(report);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
```

And part of view concerning uploads:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   <input type="file" id="fuImage" name="file" />
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   <%:Html.Label("Template") %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field"> 
   <input type="file" id="temp" name="temp"/>
</div>
<p>
   <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

I'm quite stuck in this since I can not use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` as a parameter in `Create` method because I need to save it in a different field, or can I? How should I approach this? Please help :S

Note: Image upload works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` ? You may use it like this.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(Report report, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //Let's take first file
     if(files.ElementAt(0)!=null)
     { 
       var file1=files.ElementAt(0);
       if (file1!= null && file1.ContentLength > 0)
       {
          //do processing of first file
       }
     }

     //Let's take the second one now.
     if(files.ElementAt(1)!=null)
     {
       var temp =files.ElementAt(1);
       if (temp!= null && temp.ContentLength > 0)
       {
          //do processing of second file here
       }
     }
  }
  //Do your code for saving the data. 
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**EDIT : After seeing your View Markup in your EDIT.**

The name of the file input element should be same as the parameter name in your action method. (`files` in this example)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <b>File 1</b>   
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
  <b>File 2</b>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
  <input type="submit"  />
}
```

This code assumes that read ONLY the first 2 entries from the collection.Since you wanted only 2 files, i hardcoded the indexes.

Phil has a nice blog [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) explaining about it very nicely.

Comment: I'll try it :) Thanks. Also I read that exact article you linked. Somehow didn't get that it could work like this... although i had a hunch...

Comment: Ok this works like a charm :) I want to bother you with additional question if possible :)
What If i wanted to save this second file to a folder too, but it's name should be reportid number. Would i just do something like
`var fileName = reports.reportid;
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("somepath"), fileName);
files.ElementAt(1).SaveAs(path);` ?

Comment: @user1407758: You mat need ti give the new name as part of the path when you save. I recommend you to post it as a new question with RELEVANT details.

Comment: I've tried my idea and it worked quite well. :) Thanks for everything Shyju.